# GCP: Data pre-processing before passing to cloud ai-platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml, gcp-ai-platform-notebook, gcp-ai-platform-training

I have a GCP ML pipeline in which once the .csv file is stored into the Cloud Bucket, I need to pre-process (mainly `pandas` operation) the .csv and then pass it to Google Cloud AI Platform for training.

If I do this preprocessing in the AI Platform (single training job containing both pre-process & model training), it takes a lot of time with this, not sure why, the logs does not specify anything for this time delay, but the training part is pretty fast in ai-platform.

Are we not suppose to do data preprocessing in AI Platform/ML Engine ?

I tried using Cloud Function for pre-processing, but it times out in 540 sec and that's a bottleneck for us. Also I am not sure Cloud Dataflow is best for this use case.

Basically I need to do some `python pandas` pre-processing before passing the data for AI Platform. Could you please suggest any GCP product for the same?

I know we can create a GCE instance and do everything there, but we don't want to use any of IaaS service, rather more of PaaS from GCP for scaling later.

Comment: Are you using Notebooks in AI platform to do your pre-processing? If not can you elaborate on where are you running your pre-processing in AI Platform

Comment: No, its written in the "train.py" file itself before the ".fit" call, so all preprocess & fit code is in one file which get submitted as job on ai-platform, its just series of pandas join & group by

Comment: How big is the dataset?

Comment: its is around 50 MB

Comment: Can you edit your question with a sample logic so that I am able to understand it better. 50 MB is not a big amount of data.

Comment: Did you consider to container it and to run the preprocessing in Cloud Run (Timeout is up to 900s, and with also 1vCPU dedicated to the service, not the case with function)?

Comment: I agree that Dataflow may not be needed since the training data is only 50 MB. If you want to stick with a PaaS offering, I think you could look at Cloud Run or AppEngine and avoid the 540s timeout you hit with Cloud Functions. I also think you should be able to accomplish this in AI Platform Training. What framework are you using to train? If you're using either sklearn or xgboost, you might be able to take advantage of sklearn's pipelines feature.

Comment: Here are some resources: https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/scikit/training-scikit-learn and https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/scikit/training-xgboost. If you want to stick with pandas for preprocessing, I think the first step to debugging the situation is to determine if the preprocessing bottleneck is isolated to AI Platform Training. It may repro locally.

Comment: Finally, once you determine that it is only on AI Platform Training, I would look at logs to debug the bottleneck. The "Training Logs" section of this page (https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/troubleshooting) should get you pointed in the right direction. Let me know if that's helpful.

Comment: Have you look at the Custom prediction routines? https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/prediction/docs/custom-prediction-routines